# C language, what is wrong with this?

Tags: c, xcode

I wanted to make a program that can read the right answers, check the students answers comparing with the right answers and then show the points of each. The problem is that every time that I insert the first answer the program skips the second one and jumps to the third. Here's how it turns out every time:

"Insert the answer 1: a

Insert the answer 2: Insert the answer 3:"

And here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char v[30], a[30][20];
    int i,j,c;

    for (i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
        printf("Insert the answer %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%c", &v[i]);
    }

    for(j=0; j<20; j++)
    {
        printf("Student %d\n", j+1);

        for (i=0; i<30; i++)
        {
            printf("Insert your answer %d: ", i+1);
            scanf("%c", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(j=0; j<20; j++)
    {
        c=0;
        printf("Student %d\n", j+1);

        for (i=0; i<30; i++)
        {
            if (v[i] == a[i][j])
                c=c+1;
        }

        printf("Points: %d\n", c);
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: problem is most likely in scanf returning twice. replace with readln.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf( "%c", &var );` reads exactly one character from `stdin`. So the first `scanf` reads a character and the second `scanf` reads the newline `\n`. To solve the problem, use

```
scanf( " %c", &var );
        ^----- note the space
```

Putting a space before the `%c` tells `scanf` to skip whitespace (including newlines) before reading a character.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `scanf()` leaves a `\n` in the buffer, so the second call reads that, and then the third call gets the buffer empty and waits for input.

You can clean the buffer yourself with this

```
void cleanBuffer(){
    while(getchar() != '\n');
}
```

or stop using `scanf()` and use `fgets()` instead and get the data using `sscanf()`, there are a few reasons why you'd wanna do the latter.